# how openstack create windows server instance with admin password

Tags: windows, passwords, instance, admin, openstack

After create the server by `openstack server create --image ws2k16 ...`, the result which show the `adminPass` field's value isn't correct, can't login the windows server with that value.

How to define the Administrator's password by `openstack server create`, I had try `--property admin_pass=123` or `--user-data config_file` parameter, but they can't work.

Maybe I define the parameter's value in wrong way ? How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Cloudbase is the expert for Windows on OpenStack. They provide instructions at https://cloudbase.it/openstack-windows-admin-password/, though the page is four years old and uses the `nova` client instead of the `openstack` client. Worth a try, perhaps. I don't know which hypervisor you are using; if KVM, password injection is disabled by default, and you should also read https://docs.openstack.org/nova/latest/admin/admin-password-injection.html, in particular the very last paragraph.

Comment: We are using KVM hypervisor. I resolve that by changing the cloud-init script in the Windows 2016 server, inject the password through adding some code block.